# Dúvida com exceção que não deixa iniciar um projeto Maven

Tags: maven

Não consigo iniciar um projeto Maven no Eclipse, já configurei as variáveis de ambiente e reconhei a versão. Não estou entendendo está `Exception` e como fazer para poder rodar o Maven no Eclipse

Erro:

> Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLS SSLContext not
>   available     at
>   sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)    at
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)     at
>   org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.createDefault(SSLContexts.java:51)

Answer (score 0):

como está estrutura do seu projeto? Onde você colocou o arquivo *pom.xml*? Coloca os dados do seu arquivo *pom.xml* aqui para que seja mais fácil lhe ajudar.

Comment: Consegui resolver já (configurando as dependências do Maven com o Spring mais atual)